# How do I modify my simple Python code, to take into account HTTP headers?

Tags: python, http, api, url, rest

```
def URLRequest(url, params, method="POST"):
    r  = urllib2.urlopen(url, data=urllib.urlencode(params))
    return r
```

In this method, I send a POST request to a certain URL.  What if I want to do headers as well? I want to send a dictionary of additional headers (in addition to standard headers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def URLPost(url, params, method="POST", headers = {}):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    for k, v in headers.items():
        req.add_header(k, v)
    r  = urllib2.urlopen(req, data=urllib.urlencode(params))
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

With `urllib2`, you can easily use custom "Handlers" to send additional headers etc. Or see `http.client`.